# java.net.BindException as I try to define the database settings. Why is that?

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, xmpp, openfire

While trying to define `database settings` in openfire, I get the following error (as I see in the error.log file)

```
2013.08.14 11:00:23 org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.AdminConsolePlugin - Could not start admin conosle server
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.AdminConsolePlugin.startup(AdminConsolePlugin.java:181)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.AdminConsolePlugin.initializePlugin(AdminConsolePlugin.java:216)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:483)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.access$300(PluginManager.java:80)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager$PluginMonitor.run(PluginManager.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the snapshot of `database settings interface` of openfire.

[image]

What could be the reason, I am getting this error ?

*Note: I am using mysql as part of xampp package*

Answer (score 0):

> **java.net.BindException: Address already in use**

The error usually means that the port you are trying to open is being already used by another application try using netstat to see which ports are open and then use an available port.

Also check if you are binding to the right ip address (I am assuming it would be localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down the process using the port.
You can open your command line if you're on windows and type

`netstat -na | grep LISTEN`

and that will show you all the ports currently listening.